# Oracle: Taking columns from rows and putting them side by side

Tags: oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do something in Oracle.  I have this table:

```
| id  | rownum | code      | gift |
|-----|--------|-----------|------|
|2000 |   1    | Ganymede  | 437  |
|2000 |   2    | Alpha     | 50   |
|2000 |   3    | Ambergris | 600  |
```

And the client wants it to look like this:

```
| id | code_1 | gift_1 | code_2 | gift_2 | code_3    | gift_3 |
|----|--------|--------|--------|--------|-----------|--------|
|2000|Ganymede| 437    | Alpha  | 50     | Ambergris | 600    |
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this using PIVOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       "1_CODE" AS code_1,
       "1_GIFT" AS gift_1,
       "2_CODE" AS code_2,
       "2_GIFT" AS gift_2,
       "3_CODE" AS code_3,
       "3_GIFT" AS gift_3
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(code) AS code,
  MAX(gift) AS gift
  FOR "ROWNUM" IN (1, 2, 3)
)
```

or conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE "ROWNUM" WHEN 1 THEN code END) AS code_1,
       MAX(CASE "ROWNUM" WHEN 1 THEN gift END) AS gift_1,
       MAX(CASE "ROWNUM" WHEN 2 THEN code END) AS code_2,
       MAX(CASE "ROWNUM" WHEN 2 THEN gift END) AS gift_2,
       MAX(CASE "ROWNUM" WHEN 3 THEN code END) AS code_3,
       MAX(CASE "ROWNUM" WHEN 3 THEN gift END) AS gift_3
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, "ROWNUM", code, gift ) AS
SELECT 2000, 1, 'Ganymede',  437 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2000, 2, 'Alpha',      50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2000, 3, 'Ambergris', 600 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ID | CODE_1 | GIFT_1 | CODE_2 | GIFT_2 | CODE_3 | GIFT_3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2000 | Ganymede | 437 | Alpha | 50 | Ambergris | 600 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=69fb7d1b04d180b002c0fa8ff1a9bcac)*

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was going the pivot route, but pivoting each column separately.  This answer looks far better than what I was about to do given that some of these tables want to pivot 30+ columns.

Comment: When I try this solution in Oracle 12g, it has a problem with the quoted column names.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson What problem? Can you edit the fiddle linked from the answer and replicate the issue?

Comment: That's the problem, it works in fiddle, but not when I try it on our tables.  I think it can't see that the quoted column will be in the pivot.  It tells me that the quoted column is an invalid identifier.  If I do a select without the quoted columns, I see the various 1_* and 2_* columns.

Comment: I think it's because Oracle 11g has a slightly different syntax.